# unable to send an axios request from frontend to backend using useContext hook react native

Tags: mongodb, react-native, axios, react-hooks

I was trying to send a request to backend but i received this error message

'Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're %s `%s` on a released/nullified synthetic event. %s. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). , accessing the method, timeStamp, This is a no-op function'

when i hit the button on my react native app i get that error message.

here is my signup file

```
import React, { useState, useContext}from 'react';
import {  View, TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { Card,Input,Button} from 'react-native-elements';
import {Context as AuthContext} from '../redux/authContext';

const SignUpScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const {state, signUp } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName,setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [telephoneNumber, setTelephoneNumber] = useState('');



    return(
        <View>
            <Card>
                <Input
                placeholder="First Name"
                value={firstName}
                onChange={setFirstName}/>
                <Input
                placeholder="Last Name"
                value={lastName}
                onChange={setLastName}/>
                <Input
                placeholder="Email Address"
                value={email}
                onChange={setEmail}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}/>
                <Input
                placeholder="Telephone Number"
                value={telephoneNumber}
                onChange={setTelephoneNumber}
                />
                <Input
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={setPassword}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                    <Button
                title="Enter"
                onPress={()=> signUp({firstName,lastName,email,telephoneNumber,password})}/>
            </Card>
        </View>
    )
};

SignUpScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
}

export default SignUpScreen;
```

here is my reducer file

```
import createContext from './createContext';
import mainApi from '../api/apiConnection';

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const signUp = (dispatch) => {
    return async ({firstName, lastName, email, password, telephoneNumber }) => {
        try {
            const response =  await mainApi.post('/signup',{firstName, lastName, email, password, telephoneNumber});
            console.log(response.data)
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    };
};

const login = (dispatch) => {
    return ({ email, password }) => {
    };
}

const logOut = (dispatch) => {
    return ()=> {

    }
}

export const {Provider, Context} = createContext(
    authReducer,
    {signUp,login,logOut},
    {isSignedIn: false}
);
```

here is my routes file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = mongoose.model('User')


//endpoint post request
router.post('/signup', async (req,res) => {
    const {firstName, lastName, email,telephoneNumber,password} = req.body;
    //try catch to catch duplicate emails
    try{
        const user = new User({firstName, lastName, email,telephoneNumber,password});
        //saves post request to the db
        await user.save();
        //creating a token
        const token = jwt.sign({userId:user._id},'SECRET_SESSION')
        res.send({token:token})
    } catch(err){
        return res.status(422).send(err.message)
    }
});

router.post('/signin', async (req,res)=> {
    const {email, password} =req.body;
    if(!email || !password){
        return res.status(422).send({error: 'Must provide email and password'})
    }
   const user =  await User.findOne({email:email});
   if (!user){
       res.status(422).send({error: 'Invalid password or email'})
   }
   try {
       await user.comparePassword(password);
       const token = jwt.sign({userId:user._id},'SECRET_SESSION')
        res.send({token:token})
    } catch(err){
        return res.status(422).send({error: 'Invalid password or email'})
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where is this message displayed? Is it in the backend or frontend?

Comment: its in the frontend when I press the button in my signUp.js

Comment: Okay.......I mean as to where the error occured

Comment: the error occured on the frontend when i make an axios requset by pressing the enter button on signup.js file